# How to add outline to text strip in VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor

In the Blender video sequence editor (VSE) how do you add an outline to a text strip?

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a direct way of doing this. An indirect way is to add a multiplied glow effect under the text with a black color.

1. Create a text strip, then "Add" -> "Effect Strip" -> "Glow" and move it under the strip.
   [image]
2. In the Glow's "Strip" tab set "Threshold" to minimum, "Clamp" to maximum, "Blur distance" to your desired size, "Quality" to 1 (personal preference), "Blend" to alpha over, and "multiply" to maximum.
   [image]
3. In the Glow's "Modifiers" tab "add strip modifier" -> "color balance"
   [image]
4. In the color balance set "gain" to minimum
   [image]

Comment: I once did a script for a similar process: https://gist.github.com/tin2tin/b8e7fb9156b5c5d54fdab5d808dc7c1f
When installed, it'll be exposed in the Text Strip sidebar.